# How can i get smooth scroll effect on all website?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem and I want to find an answer, but I can't. Can anyone help me with a smooth page scroll effect but I don't want the effect on clicking a link or diva or other things. I just always want this effect.
The effect is here:
https://webflow.com/made-in-webflow/website/Webflow-Smooth-Scroll-Luxyjs

Thanks for help anyone!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: please give more information thank you @Agent

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `luxy,js` and follow this steps:

1. install it: `npm install luxy.js --save`
2. add script in end of your body tag `<script src="path/to/luxy.js" charset="utf-8"></script>`
3. initialize luxy `<script charset="utf-8">luxy.init();</script>`
4. then use it `<div id="luxy">...content</div>`

more info about `luxy.js` [click here](https://github.com/min30327/luxy.js).